# When and who executes a Method call?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, overriding

I use a simple method call to execute methods in other classes.

When I use this combined with two Threads and a BlockingQueue I asked my self, which thread and when this calls are executed.

I made a pseudo code example which is not really useful, but describing the case:

## Thread A

```java
public class ThreadA extends Thread {
  private static final String TAG = "ThreadA";

  @Override
  public void run() {

    ThreadB threadB = new ThreadB();
    threadB.start();
    InputStream InPut = null;//Imagen this inputStream results out of any kind 
                             //of connection (Bluetooth,...)
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    while (true){
      try {
        InPut.read(buffer);
        threadB.send(buffer+"");
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Thread B

```java
public class ThreadB extends Thread {
  private static final String TAG = "ThreadB";

  private BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true){
      String st ="";
      try {
        st = queue.take();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      Log.d(TAG, "String is: " + st);
    }
  }
    

  public void send(String a) {
    queue.add(a);
  }
}
```

Szenario: When Thread B is blocked in the `.take()` but the method gets called, how does this work?

My question results out of the observation, that the inputstream in Thread A reads wrong data when I use this.

Comment: What is your definition of "wrong data"? take() will block waiting for the queue to signal. You can have a look at how that works in the actual code. It's available online or in your local JDK files.

Comment: @Flidor The received data should be about 1- 10 byte with some information.
The actually received data when using the method call is up to 20 bytes.
The first view bytes contain correct data, but the rest is just wrong useless data.

Comment: You don't seem to reset the buffer. The [read operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) should give you an int that is the count of actually read bytes. You should then pass only that portion of the buffer ( 0 to count-1 ).

Comment: @Flidor I'm talking about this. When I use the Method call, the `.read` returns me 20 In the real code I do what you say, like using the amount of read bytes to only pass the actual read data, but when it returns 20 it will pass 20.

Comment: OK, the example is a little misleading, then.

Comment: Nevertheless, it has noting to do with your threading. It's a little unusual to me, but it should work just fine. So it's either the source itself or maybe your way to turn the bytes into a string. _Are_ those bytes guaranteed to be able to just interpret them as a java string?

Comment: @Fildor No the bytes should not be directly converted to a String, but the problem already appears in the `read()` line. I don't understand why my InputStream is different when I use this thread.

Comment: Now I am confused. Different to what? Did you try without extra thread before?

Comment: When I use Thread A without Thread B the length of read bytes is between 1-10 which is nice.
When I additional start start Thread B the length of read bytes is between 19 - 25 which should be not possible.

Comment: That is really odd. Maybe (if you can) post the original code. There must be something that your example does not show.

Comment: I will start debugging and come back later with more data and results. I will probably make a new question, since the question of executed code is answered now. Thank you for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
threadB.send(buffer+"");
```

I am assuming your confusion is regarding this call. This is a method called by threadA.

To understand this in general, you need to differentiate between the Thread Java Objects and actual OS threads. The Java Thread Objects are not the "real" threads, they are just the representative of the thread.

If start() is called on a thread object, it creates a new "real" OS thread which runs the run() method. The other methods you call on such a thread object, like join(), are methods you call on the current thread, but which trigger OS system calls which interact with the "real" threads. That there is a method inside a Thread subclass that you call has nothing to do with what thread executes it, it is always the current thread.

Comment: Okay, but when would use a public method like `send()` from above inside the thread (in the `run()` of Thread B) and Thread A, is it the same than?

Comment: `send` is executed on Thread A. But the queue will signal and wake up Thread B to continue execution of ThreadB's `run`.

Comment: When Thread B is blocked through `take()` and Thread A executes `send()` is it possible that Thread A has to wait, because calling the OS is only possible when B is not blocked ? Or is this like totally independent?

Comment: Btw: You can test that if you give the thread a unique name during creation and in the method make an output of current thread's name property.

Comment: @HydroHeiperGen Then all blocking collections would be useless. Thread A can execute queue.Add (via ThreadB.send) if Thread B is waiting or not. Does not matter. That's the whole point of blocking collections.

Comment: How to realize such a Output?

Comment: @HydroHeiperGen `System.out.println("Methodname executed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());` for example. If you have a logging Framework in place, you may be able to include a Thread ID or name in the log output automagically.